# Is it possible to programmatically search Python's middle scopes?

Tags: python, scope, stack-trace

Consider the Python code where `function1` has `x` defined in its local scope. I am wondering if it is possible to write `go_up_stack_and_find("x")` so that it will go up the stack, through the middle scopes and find "x" in the locals() of those scopes:

```py
def function1(): 
    x = 1 
    function2() 


def function2(): 
    go_up_stack_and_find("x")
```

I understand Python's scoping rules (local and global) and understand that the middle scopes are not generally available. But is it possible (say through a stacktrace) to programmatically go up the stack, inspecting locals() and return the value from that depth? I know it is possible with the debuggers.

Comment: Yes, using `sys._getframe()` and the `inspect` module.

Comment: Python is statically scoped; what you are trying to do is equivalent to dynamic scoping.

Comment: Python 3 has the `nonlocal` statement to walk up the list of *static* scopes.